# Turning the second timeseries in a TimeseriesChart to a barchart

Tags: java, jfreechart, timeserieschart

As the heading implies, I have a timeseries chart that displays two curves, each a TimeSeries, both part of the same TimeSeriesCollection. What I want to do is display the second TimeSeries as a barchart, but I want both TimeSeries still in the same chart. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes this is possible, look at the OverlaidXYPlotDemo1 and OverlaidXYPlotDemo2 charts in the sample demo application that you can run from the JFree site.  If you purchase the documentation they will send you the actual code for all the samples.