# JFreeChart: How to plot a line graph and a scatter on same chart

Tags: java, jfreechart, scatter-plot, line-plot

i have two sets of data

```
int[] x1 = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
int[] y1 = {1,2,3,5,6,8,9,10,14,11};

int[] x2 = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
int[] y2 = {0,2,3,5,0,8,9,8,14,11};

int[] z2 = {1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,1};
```

I want to plot the `x1,y1` as an `XYLineChart` and then plot `x2,y2` as a scatter on the same plot without a line.

I also need each scatter point of `xy,y2` to be a different color depending on the value of `z2` `(1=Color.red, 2=Color.green, 3=Color.blue)`

How can i do this?

So far i have:

```
JPanel panel_1 = new JPanel();
panel_1.setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));
XYSeriesCollection dataset = new XYSeriesCollection();
XYSeries series1 = new XYSeries("series1");
for(int i=0; i<x1.length; i++){
    series1.add(x1[i],y1[i]);
}
dataset.add(series1);
JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createXYLineChart("Title", "x", "y", dataset, PlotOrientation.VERTICAL, false, false, false);
ChartPanel cp = new ChartPanel(chart);
panel_1.add(cp, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

This gets the line graph sorted. I now need to code the scatter plot for `x2,y2` (with colors described above) which is where im stuck.

Comment: Take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6076133/turning-the-second-timeseries-in-a-timeserieschart-to-a-barchart not exactly the same but related. Have you tried adding a second renderer? See http://code.google.com/p/swing-ui-hxzon/source/browse/trunk/jfreechart/org/jfree/chart/demo/OverlaidXYPlotDemo2.java?r=65&spec=svn65 for a copy of the sample code.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The createXYLineChart() method will create a chart that uses an [XYLineAndShapeRenderer](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/renderer/xy/XYLineAndShapeRenderer.html).  So fetch the renderer from the plot and cast it to XYLineAndShapeRenderer.  Then you can call the methods [setSeriesLinesVisible()](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/renderer/xy/XYLineAndShapeRenderer.html#setSeriesLinesVisible%28int,%20java.lang.Boolean%29) and [setSeriesShapesVisible()](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/renderer/xy/XYLineAndShapeRenderer.html#setSeriesShapesVisible%28int,%20boolean%29) to control, for each series, whether shapes and/or lines are drawn for the data items.  That way you can use a single renderer and dataset, which makes things simpler.

Your requirement to change the colors depending on another data value requires a little more work.  You should subclass the XYLineAndShapeRenderer class and override the [getItemPaint(int, int)](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/renderer/AbstractRenderer.html#getItemPaint%28int,%20int%29) method.  Here you can return any color you want for a data item.  The default implementation looks at the series index and returns the color for the series.  You need to look at the item index as well, then do a lookup in your table of z-values and decide what color to return.