# How do I remove the points in XYLineAndShapeRenderer?

Tags: java, jfreechart

I'm making an application in Java using JFreeChart which shows an XY line chart. The problem is that it shows every point of the dataset on the lines, and I don't want to display these points. Any idea on how to remove the points or make them not visible?

This is a sample screenshot:

[image]

Here is the code:

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame();                
XYLineAndShapeRenderer renderer = new XYLineAndShapeRenderer();
renderer.setSeriesPaint(0, Color.RED);
renderer.setSeriesStroke(0, new BasicStroke(2.0f, 
BasicStroke.CAP_ROUND, BasicStroke.JOIN_ROUND, 1.0f,
    new float[] { 2.0f, 4.0f }, 0.0f));
XYDataset ds = createDataset(i, p, capacity);
JFreeChart xylineChart = ChartFactory.createXYLineChart("", "", 
"", ds, PlotOrientation.VERTICAL, true, true, false);
XYPlot plot = xylineChart.getXYPlot();
plot.setDomainGridlinePaint(Color.BLACK);
plot.setRangeGridlinePaint(Color.BLACK);
plot.setBackgroundPaint(Color.WHITE);
plot.setRenderer(renderer);
ChartPanel cp = new ChartPanel(xylineChart);
frame.getContentPane().add(cp);
```

Comment: Can you update your question with code

Comment: What part of the code do you want to see? Because there's a lot of code unrelated with the chart and I don't want to post it all

Comment: only that used for graph generation

Comment: I think it was that one, if i don't mix it up with the legend(try it - if you had given a code I could have checked it ;) ): http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/renderer/xy/XYLineAndShapeRenderer.html#setSeriesShapesVisible-int-boolean-

Comment: thaks, it worked

Answer (score 3):

By default, the [no-argument constructor](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/renderer/xy/XYLineAndShapeRenderer.html#XYLineAndShapeRenderer--) of [`XYLineAndShapeRenderer`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/renderer/xy/XYLineAndShapeRenderer.html) "Creates a new renderer with both lines and shapes visible." To remove the points, you can

- Use the [alternative constructor](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/renderer/xy/XYLineAndShapeRenderer.html#XYLineAndShapeRenderer-boolean-boolean-) to specify the desired combination—lines without shapes, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10353270/230513) and in [`ChartFactory.createXYLineChart`](https://github.com/jfree/jfreechart/blob/master/src/main/java/org/jfree/chart/ChartFactory.java#L1726):

  ```
  XYLineAndShapeRenderer renderer = new XYLineAndShapeRenderer(true, false);
  ```
- Invoke `setSeriesShapesVisible()`, as @abhinavxeon suggests [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54804499/how-do-i-remove-the-points-in-xylineandshaperenderer#comment96385874_54804499) and [the author](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2592874/david-gilbert) suggests [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19510171/230513):

  ```
  renderer.setSeriesShapesVisible(0, false)
  ```